# pythonを使用した線形代数の計算について

Tags: python, numpy

pythonでnumpyを使用した線形代数問題の解き方に詰まっています。

A=100％でXの値7、Ｙの値1、Ｚの値6.5
B=100%でXの値1.2、Ｙの値1.2、Ｚの値1.8
C=100%でXの値0.5、Ｙの値8.5、Ｚの値0.95

例題
目標：X=7、Ｙ=1、Ｚ=6.5＃答えＡ＝100％、Ｂ＝0％、Ｃ＝0％
目標：X=1.2、Ｙ=1.2、Ｚ=1.8＃答えＡ＝0％、Ｂ＝100％、Ｃ＝0％
目標：X=0.5、Ｙ=8.5、Ｚ=0.95＃答えＡ＝0％、Ｂ＝0％、Ｃ＝100％
目標：X=0.109、Ｙ=0.289、Ｚ=0.1295＃答えＡ＝1％、Ｂ＝2％、Ｃ＝3％
目標：X=8.7、Ｙ=10.7、Ｚ=9.25＃答えＡ＝100％、Ｂ＝100％、Ｃ＝100％

A,B,Cのパーセンテージを調整してA,B,CそれぞれのX,Y,Z足した時、目標のX,Y,Zの値に合わせるコードを製作しているのですがなかなかうまくいきません。numpyを使用して線形代数を使用すればいいというところまではいったのですがそこで止まっています。

Comment: NumPyでの解決方法, という質問でしょうか？それとも別な方法でも構わない？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

行列で方程式解くので, 縦横逆で

```py
import numpy as np

mat = np.array([[7.0, 1.2, 0.5],
                [1.0, 1.2, 8.5],
                [6.5, 1.8, 0.95]])

r = np.array([0.109, 0.289, 0.1295])
np.rint(np.linalg.solve(mat, r) *100)

# array([1., 2., 3.])
```

Answer (score 0):

SymPy 使う方法
(数値(浮動小数点数)の誤差が少ないはず)

```py
from sympy import symbols, Matrix, solve

a, b, c = symbols('a b c')
mat1, mat2, mat3 = Matrix([7, 1, 6.5]), Matrix([1.2, 1.2, 1.8]), Matrix([0.5, 8.5, 0.95])

expr = a*mat1 +b*mat2 +c*mat3
display(expr)
solve(expr - Matrix([0.109, 0.289, 0.1295]))
```

[image: SymPy結果]